# How to create drawer and bottom nav bar together in flutter?

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview, drawer

I searched everywhere but i unable to find that how to use drawer and bottom nav bar together in flutter ?

I created both ui for both are displaying good. The main problem is that i can navigate either drawer's items class or bottom nav bar class in body. If bottom item clicked the bottom class should be loaded and when drawer's item clicked then its class should be loaded.

My code is below please see the code if any mistake or suggest me any example. Thankx in advance!!

```
  '''
  //for setting title name of side bar items
    class DrawerItem {
      String title;
      IconData icon;
    
      DrawerItem(this.title, this.icon);
    }
    
    //for setting title name of bottom bar items
    // class widgetBottomItems{
    //   String title;
    //   IconData icon;
    //   widgetBottomItems(this.title, this.icon);
    // }
    
    class DrawerSetting extends StatefulWidget {
      final drawerItems = [
        new DrawerItem("Add Manual FD", Icons.add),
        new DrawerItem("Zero Balance Portfolio", Icons.alarm),
        new DrawerItem("Message", Icons.message),
        new DrawerItem("My Info & Setting", Icons.settings),
        new DrawerItem("Support", Icons.help),
        new DrawerItem("FAQ", Icons.book_outlined),
        new DrawerItem("Contact Us", Icons.contact_phone_outlined),
        new DrawerItem("Logout", Icons.logout)
      ];
    
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return new HomePageState();
      }
    }
    
    class HomePageState extends State<DrawerSetting> {
      final Color myColor = Color(0xFF15A2EB);
      final Color myColorLightGray = Color(0xFF989E9E);
      final Color text_Semi_Black_Color = Color(0xFF414B51);
      final Color text_gray_color = Color(0xFF70787C);
    
      int _selectedDrawerIndex = 0;
    
      //bottom navigation
      int _selectedIndex = 0;
      var _screens = [
        DiscoverScreen(),
        HomeFragment(),
        PartnersScreen(),
        // HistoryScreen(),
        AppHistoryTabScreen(),
      ];
      static const TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: Colors.red,
        fontFamily: "verdana_regular",
      );
      static const List<Widget> widgetBottomItems = <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Discover',
          style: optionStyle,
        ),
        Text(
          'Portfolio',
          style: optionStyle,
        ),
        Text(
          'Partners',
          style: optionStyle,
        ),
        Text(
          'History',
          style: optionStyle,
        ),
      ];
    
      String currentProfilePic =
          "https://service2home.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/rakesh.jpg";
    
      _getDrawerItemWidget(int pos) {
        switch (pos) {
          case 0:
            return new AddManualFdFragment();
            break;
          case 1:
            return new ZeroBalancePortFolioScreen();
            break;
          case 2:
            return MessageFragment();
            break;
          case 3:
            return new UserProfileScreen("drawer");
            break;
          case 4:
            return new SupportFragment();
            break;
          case 5:
            return new FAQFragment();
            break;
          case 6:
            return new ContactUsScreen();
            break;
          case 7:
            SystemNavigator.pop();
            //exit(0);
            break;
        }
      }
    
      //for bottom items
      void _onItemTapped(int index) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
          //calling both items
          // _onSelectItem(index);
        });
      }
    
      //for drawer items
      _onSelectItem(int index) {
        setState(() => _selectedDrawerIndex = index);
        Navigator.of(context).pop(); // close the drawer
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        List<Widget> drawerOptions = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < widget.drawerItems.length; i++) {
          var d = widget.drawerItems[i];
          drawerOptions.add(new ListTile(
            leading: new Icon(
              d.icon,
            ),
            title: new Text(
              d.title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: myColorLightGray,
                fontFamily: "verdana_regular",
              ),
            ),
            selected: i == _selectedDrawerIndex,
            onTap: () => _onSelectItem(i),
          ));
        }
    
        //on backpress return to home screen , you can use it for drawer items
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () {
            if (_selectedIndex != 0) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = 0;
              });
              _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedIndex);
            } else {
              Navigator.pop(context, true);
            }
            return;
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text(
                widget.drawerItems[_selectedDrawerIndex].title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: "verdana_regular"),
              ),
            ),
            drawer: new Drawer(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: new Column(
                  children: [
                    UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                      currentAccountPicture: Container(
                        child: new GestureDetector(
                          child: new CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(currentProfilePic),
                          ),
                          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => UserProfileScreen("header")),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      accountName: new Text(
                        "Rakesh saini",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily: "verdana_regular",
                        ),
                      ),
                      accountEmail: new Text(
                        "rakesh.ollosoft@gmail.com",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: "verdana_regular",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(children: drawerOptions)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: /*_screens[_selectedIndex]*/
                _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex),
    
            //bottom navigation bar
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              backgroundColor: myColor,
              items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  label: 'Discover',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage("assets/images/briefcase.png"),
                    // color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  label: 'Portfolio',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage("assets/images/handshake.png"),
                    // color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  label: 'Partners',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.history),
                  label: 'History',
                ),
              ],
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
              selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
              unselectedItemColor: myColorLightGray,
              onTap: _onItemTapped,
            ),
            // bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      //go to news detail page
      void goToProfile_Screen(BuildContext ctx) {
        Navigator.of(ctx).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) {
              return UserProfileScreen("drawer");
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  
  '''
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all my friend that is a very bad code.

in this code below I have both of what you want you can follow this path

FooterNavigationBar is just a stateful widget with some row and container nothing special

```
Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  bottomNavigationBar: FooterNavigationBar(),
  drawer: AppDrawer(
    scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey,
  ),
  backgroundColor: CBase().backgroundColor,
  body: ......
       InkWell(
          onTap: () {
             _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
             },
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              "images/DrawerIcon.svg"),
                   ),
              ...............
```

Comment: I am beginner in flutter, please post full code, it will be better understandable for me.